# Careers Relocate to X thinks London is too vague (and displays badly)

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, location

In my employer search options I want to state that I am willing to relocate to London, but apparently that's not specific enough:

> Sorry, we need a more specific location than 'London, United Kingdom'. Try again?

I tried 'Central London, United Kingdom', but the word central gets stripped.  I don't know how specific it wants me to be, but I think that London as a whole should be a perfectly valid choice, and so I'm calling this a bug.  Expecting me to define every area of London separately seems unnecessary.

Furthermore, the above quoted error message does not display correctly in Chrome, FireFox or IE9:

[image]

Comment: There was an opposite bug a while back I think with London being empty.

Comment: The issue seems to have been fixed now. Thank you to whoever did it.